# Variable parameter in transform scale() svg document

Tags: variables, parameters, svg, arguments, transform

In a SVG file, I want to define some global constants values in the defs section (or any other relevant node) to be reused as a scale parameter.

```
<svg:defs id="defs4">
xxxx value defined here
</svg:defs>

...

<svg:g id="id1" transform="scale(xxxx)">...</svg:g>
```

PS : there is no scripting involved here
I've tried the param() function without any success...
Is it even possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be extremely simple using javascript. Is there a specific reason as to why you can't use a scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [SVG parameters specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParam/) but it's still being written and not implemented by any UAs natively yet. There are some examples of how it would work in the [primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/)  but they are currently implemented using javascript. Future UAs that implemented the parameters specification once it is complete would not need scripting to be turned on for parameters to work.